# Blueprints Python-Flask en Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

En mi aplicacion en python-flask uso Blueprints para modularizarla.
En local funciona sin problema.
En Heroku las urls de los Blueprints dan todas error 404, no las encuentra.
Alguien sabe que puede estar ocurriendo?

Gracias.

Comment: Sin ver el código solo Dios sabe que ocurre.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.